How to toggle the visibility of the right sidebar in vscode?
I'm using Visual Studio Code and currently have the right sidebar (where extensions like Copilot and other AI extension) open. I want to toggle its visibility without using the mouse, ideally through a keyboard shortcut.
Is there a default keybinding for this, or do I need to configure a custom one? If so, how can I set up a custom keyboard shortcut for toggling the right sidebar?
I'm looking for a solution that works across all platforms (Windows, Mac, Linux).

You can open the View -> Appearance -> Secondary Side Bar.
or Just use  Ctrl+Alt+B to toggle the Secondary Side Bar.
